plot XY data on livecharts Library C#
I can successfully plot data on my chart with code below:
        private async Task DataPlotterAsync(double Data, TimeSpan DeltaT, string Data_Name, string X_Axis_Label, string Y_Axis_Label, LiveCharts.WinForms.CartesianChart Chart, Bunifu.Framework.UI.BunifuCheckbox related_Checkbox, NumericUpDown relatedNumericUpdown)
        {
            await Task.Run(() =>
            {

                Chart.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() =>
                {
                    double X = (double)DeltaT.TotalMilliseconds / 1000;
                    // Convert the seriesView object to a LineSeries
                    var series = (LineSeries)Chart.Series[0];

                   

                    series.Values.Add(Data);

                    if (related_Checkbox.Checked == true)
                    {
                        if (series.Values.Count > relatedNumericUpdown.Value)
                        {
                            Chart.AxisX[0].MinValue = series.Values.Count - (double)relatedNumericUpdown.Value;
                            Chart.AxisX[0].MaxValue = series.Values.Count;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                        try
                        {
                            Chart.AxisX[0].MinValue = 1;
                            Chart.AxisX[0].MaxValue = series.Values.Count;
                        }
                        catch
                        {
                            // nothing // the very first time series.Values.Count equals 1 and the try part fails. This catch helped me circumvent fatal error
                        }

                    Chart.Update();

                }));



            });

        }

Although this works fine, I want to use time for X axis of my charts.
I found a solution on Internet:
series.Values.Add(new ObservablePoint(X, Data));


But this returns error. "System.InvalidCastException: 'Specified cast is not valid.'"
Also I am running code below in form1 initialization:
            Chart1.Series = new LiveCharts.SeriesCollection
            {
                new LiveCharts.Wpf.LineSeries
                {
                    Values = new LiveCharts.ChartValues<double> { 3, 5, 7, 7, 9, 24, 41, 3, 1,  }
                },
            };


Maybe, Since I am creating a wpf.lineseries, I can not plot XY points on my chart.

Can you please [edit] your question and tell us which error you get?

I did it. Sorry.
